# Is it common to use MRT to refer to subways all around the world?

Tags: word-usage

According to [The Free Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_Rapid_Transit):

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mass+rapid+transit

> Noun  1.  mass rapid transit - an urban public transit system using
>   underground or elevated trains rapid transit public transit - a public
>   transportation system for moving passengers

I found strange that the [Wikipedia MRT entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_Rapid_Transit) only lists certain countries, mainly in Asia.

Is MRT a common word to refer to subways all around the world?

(Because I used MRT to describe the subway system in Japan. I want to know if the use was inappropriate. If it was, which word should I have used?)

Comment: I thought you meant magnetic resonance therapy. And I am not a doctor, and I do use public transport every single day. So I guess that's a clear no from me.

Comment: No it is not.... Subway, Metro, Underground are used much more than this which I had to read a few times

Comment: "Rapid transit system" is used as a technical term (I trained as a civil engineer many years ago), but it's not in common vernacular use in the West.

Comment: So what's more common: train station, subway station, or metro station?

Comment: janoChen, the answer is going to depend on which part of the world someone is talking about or, which kind of English someone uses. For example, *subway* and *MRT* are not part of the terminology used in the UK.

Comment: You should use the terminology for the specific subway/underground system you are referring to.  If it's Paris it's the Metro, if it's San Francisco it's BART, if it's Phoenix it's  the Light Rail, if it's Boston it's the T, in Chicago it's the L, etc.

Comment: As far as Japan is concerned, I guess it depends on what it's called in Japanese and how that is *translated* into English. Or: use the English term understood by your target readership. (But as Jim indicates, there are a number of local terms, nothing much generic. And he missed [*Tube*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_map).)

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6814/whats-the-difference-between-subway-metro-and-tube

Comment: Local transportation systems, like local foods, acquire local nicknames. In Boston it's the ***T***, in Chicago it's the ***L***, in Paris it's the ***Métro***, in London it's the ***Tube***, etc. I know of no internationally used TLA that is common in use.

Comment: John, in London, it's also the **Underground**, which is a short way of saying the **London Underground**.

Comment: Both "subway" and "metro" are common names for rapid transit systems (although I believe "subway" generally is only used for systems with a substantial underground component). I've never heard of MRT.

Comment: "Rapid transit" is reasonably idiomatic in the US, though the definition may be a bit fuzzy from person to person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think a layman would think of a train network upon hearing *MRT* except in Bangkok, Singapore, and other cities where it happens to be part of the official name.

As you can see from [Wikipedia's page on passenger rail terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_rail_terminology), there is no single common word for these transportation systems (beyond *train* or *railway* perhaps), because there is no universally agreed upon set of characteristics for them, because local usage varies from the definitions of transportation planners, and because individual systems themselves blur the lines and contradict parts of their own names. If you do choose a common name, you will need to define it.

Local usage prevails. In Chicago, the *subway* refers to the underground portions of the Blue and Red lines of the "L." On the other hand, many Philadelphia natives refer to the whole Blue Line, whose downtown portion is entirely underground, as *the El*. In New York, the entire urban system operated by the MTA is called the Subway, including both underground and elevated portions. Yet no part of the coexisting PATH system, underground or above ground, is called the subway; it is simply *the PATH* (or for an older generation, *the tubes*). Confusing the PATH for the Subway just because it is a subway will mark you as a tourist. Washington's Metro is a regional, not a metropolitan system, and the Metropolitan Atlanta Rapid Transit Authority operates many more non-rapid (i.e. bus) routes than rapid (i.e. rapid rail) ones.

You'll also encounter problems of overlapping and conflicting terminology in discussing *freeways* / *expressways* / *motorways*, but both of these pale in comparison to the debates over what constitutes a *car* / *motorcar* , *automobile*, or *motor vehicle*.

Answer (score -1):

I think it was inappropriate as people in Japan may not know what you meant by MRT. You should have instead said 'train' or 'subway'